# Disable automatic (preview) window (buffer) with a function signature

Tags: vim, python-mode

Every time I click dot, the function signature appears in a separate buffer.

```
import sys

sys.argv   # in this moment I have a separate buffer opened with sys.argv signature
```

Then this buffer exists until manually closed.

I'd like to have it only when I press `ctrl-K`. Or at least it disappears when I exit insert mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realize that this buffer is called `preview window`. Thus the `:pc` or simply `<C-w-C-z>` works to close it

```
CTRL-W CTRL-Z                   *CTRL-W_CTRL-Z* *:pc* *:pclose*
:pc[lose][!]    Close any "Preview" window currently open.  When the 'hidden'
        option is set, or when the buffer was changed and the [!] is
        used, the buffer becomes hidden (unless there is another
        window editing it).  The command fails if any "Preview" buffer
        cannot be closed.  See also |:close|.
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found the solution:

add

I added youCompleteMe plugin:

`Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'`

and

`let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1`

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of the Rope AutoCompletion used in Python-Mode.

https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/01c3131343aaa3c76f8cb656b5e9f54ac90ca04b/doc/pymode.txt#L476

If you dont like the behavior, you can turn it off using

let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 1

The reason its working when you use YouCompleteMe, is because YouCompleteMe is turning off the whole python-mode plugin altogehter. So while you can get ride of this issue, you will lose all the other features of python-mode as well.

Comment: I added this line to vimrc and commented `let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1`. However I still have the problem. What can go wrong?

Comment: Forgot to add, that it seems python-mode still working. for example it lint my code on save

Comment: Also clean completely AutoCompleteMe. Doesn't help.